# Intuitive explanation of connectdness in relation to SO(3) and 3-sphere

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, quaternions

I am a part time computer engineering student which works in the field of computer graphics. I am forcing myself to get to know deeper tha math I work with and I am a bit stuck on the concept of gimbal lock from a topological point of view.

Could someone try to explain both formally and more intuitevely why euler angles are SO(3)/toroidal and not simply connected while quaternions are? and why quaternions have a covering map to the real projective space?

Thanks!

Comment: SO(3) is real real projective space of dimension 3. If that helps.

Comment: @AnubhavMukherjee uhm... I guess I am just very confused about the argument, how should I interpretate this from wikipedia:
RP3 is (diffeomorphic to) SO(3), hence admits a group structure; the covering map S3 → RP3 is a map of groups Spin(3) → SO(3), where Spin(3) is a Lie group that is the universal cover of SO(3). 
I mean, if SO(3) is real projective space, then why there there is no covering map? it is like saying something is different from itself?

Comment: Let me write down how intuitively you can see it.